# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pro.csv'

Tags: python, windows, file-permissions

> I want to change the null values in the dataset to "not mentioned" but
>   unable to do so. I am new to this so if any naive error , I apologize.
>   Please help.

```
Name: website, Length: 2407, dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project1.py", line 19, in <module>
    df.to_csv("pro.csv", index=False)
  File "C:\Users\Lucifer Morningstar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3228, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "C:\Users\Lucifer Morningstar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py", line 183, in save
    compression=self.compression,
  File "C:\Users\Lucifer Morningstar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 399, in _get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'pro.csv'
```

My program code is :-

```
#Data Cleaning with Python Pandas
#Missing Values

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Standard Missing Values
df = pd.read_csv("breweries_us.csv")
a=df["website"]
b=df["website"].isnull()
print(a)
print(b)

#replacing missing values
c=df["website"]
df["website"].fillna("not mentioned",inplace=True)
d=df["website"]
print(d)
df.to_csv("pro.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: It is rather obvious, I guess. The OS is saying that you do not have the permissions required to save to that filename.

Comment: Possibly the working directory isn't what you expect it to be. print `os.getcwd()`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issues. Basically, I was trying to convert `.xml` to `.csv`. I did it. However, I made a mistake when I reviewed the file, I found that I made a mistake in a file naming.

### Filename before

`example.png.png`

### Filename After

`example.png`

While I was trying to fix I forgot to close the opened file. Therefore I could not generate another or modify the CSV file.

```py
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'train_labels.csv'
```

I learned to close the file first before I modify it.

I hope it will help another person.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the file's location is probably restricted by someone with higher authority than you on the system. In case need to you have access to such an account (Admin or whoever is controlling the permissions in that folder?)

Two solutions:

1. Go to the said folder and change the folder's access permissions. You can access that by selecting the folder in the file explorer -> right click -> properties -> Security and see (and change) your access to that folder's files.
2. Or you can run your execution environment (Command prompt, is it? or python IDLE?) with administrator privileges (Right click the said program -> Run with Administrator) so that you are in a group that can access that folder.

I would personally recommend option #1 since it's a more permanent solution in case you are not a privileged user of this particular system and need to call someone else for allowing you access.

Answer (score 0):

Also one of the things that helped fix this error for me is before running the python file you should not have the csv open.